# Java shared references between threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

We're looking for a library/functionality in Java (in a spring framework context) for passing references between threads:

```
//ParentThread:
XXX.putSharedObject("lock", childLock);
XXX.putSharedObject("someKey", someObjectInstance);
for(i=0;i<X;i++) { taskExecutor.execute(context.getBean("childClass")); }
childLock.wait(xxx);

//ChildThread:
YY = XXX.getSharedObject("someKey");
YY.someFunction();
...some work...
XXX.getSharedObject("lock").notify();
```

Such that any reference set in XXX by a thread (ParentThread) will be accessible only to 'ParentThread' and any child of it, but not other 'ParentThreads' or their children.

Is that possible? (I believe its kind of how Mapped Diagnostic Context work in logging frameworks)

Thanks

Comment: With my best capability of parsing your question, I think you might be looking for [`java.lang.ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

Comment: Isn't that per thread itself? ie can ThreadLocal variable defined by 'ParentThread' be accessible by 'ChildThread' without each time passing it in the constructor? (in this case, getting a bean from spring context, and calling a 'setter' for all references?)

Comment: Apparently there is a [`java.lang.InheritableThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InheritableThreadLocal.html).

Comment: InheritableThreadLocals may sertainly work...trying it out

Comment: InheritableThreadLocals works so far: parent defines it as "public static final" then calls set() and child calls ParentClass.XXX.get() which achieves the desired behaviour...appreciate it @M.leRutte (wanna add an answer?)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out. It's fine, you can answer your question yourself for future coders.

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out like this (Compliments of [M. le Rutte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993392/m-le-rutte)):

```
//ParentRunnable:
public static final InheritableThreadLocal<SomeObjectType> YY = new InheritableThreadLocal<SomeObjectType>();

@Override
public void run() {
  ...
  YY.set(someObjectInstance);
  logger.debug("InParent: {}", YY.get());
  for(i=0;i<X;i++) { taskExecutor.execute(context.getBean("childClass")); }
}


//ChildRunnable:
@Override
public void run() {
  logger.debug("InChild: {}", ParentRunnable.YY.get());
}
```

The nice part is also that:

```
@Override
protected SomeObjectType initialValue()
```

can throw an exception to hint calling "get()" prematurely before a "set()", or use the application context to get a prototype bean which is used as a singleton between the children.

Hope this is helpful to anyone needing it (and hopefully also correctly written)

Answer (score 0):

Java shared references can be achieved with thread safety using a synchronized class or even a block or a method. This way, you can share a given object between threads(Parent,child ...) and guarantee thread safety.

Comment: Thread safety is not a problem here (assuming for instance YY.someFunction(); is thread safe here), the problem is avoiding calling setters for each loader inside the for loop, and all types of Threads which need to share a set of common references.

Comment: Again, kind of like how MDC works in logging libraries (like Log4J)